# What is the simplest way of sharing my world with a friend?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I want to share my single player world with my friend, Can someone tell me how but in a simple way (I'm on a mac)

I'm really having trouble and I want to share my world with my friend.

Comment: When you say share, do you mean play in the same world at the same time?

Comment: If what Timmy asks is true, Will your friend play at your house, or do you want to play together over the internet?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean you want to play with them, then you can either meet at one of your houses and play on the Local Area Network, or you can get in to setting up a dedicated server. See [setting up a server.](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Tutorials/Setting_up_a_server)

If you mean you just wish to send them a copy of your world to see, you can go to "~/Library/Application Support/minecraft" to access your save data and compress the world save folder to one file.

Please note that the Library folder is hidden by default on a Mac, so you'll need to access the folder using Finder's Go to Folder function (⇧ + ⌘ + G to access) and paste that location into the menu.